# How to determine from which path the page has been opened in php?

Tags: php, html

I have a lot of links on a page, which have the the same href (address) . How can i get to know from which link that url has been opened. I want to perform different actions subsequently depending on the link used to approach that address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add paramaters to the links. For example:
Think that you have two menus:

```
<div id="menu1">
   <a href="link1.php?menu=1" >Link 1</a>
</div>
<div id="menu2">
     <a href="link1.php?menu=2" >Link 1</a>
</div>
```

In the link1.php  you can get the menu value using `$_GET['menu']`.

Also you can store those data in a session variable or a database table.

If the visitor clicks `Link 1` in `#menu1` you would get

```
$refererMenu = $_GET['menu']; //1
```

Comment: can u plz explain in a bit more detail?